# Printing Issue - Ubuntu 16x Server

Tags: 16.04, server, printing

Setting up secondary server identical to primary. HP network printer. When send text file to printer "lp /etc/samba/smb.conf" on secondary server I get "request id is M651Admin-3 (1 file(s))".  Printing works on primary server

M651Admin is the HP printer. The "3" is (I am guessing) the number of times I sent this to the printer.  This works on my primary box, but not the secondary, which I followed identical steps to setup.  I've restarted cups, rebooted, but to no avail.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically it gives no error message....just doesn't print.  And yes it can ping the printer, no security on the printer...job never makes it in queue of printer.

Comment: So you have m651dn, connected via ethernet to the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, right? [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) says that it needs HPLIP 3.14.4 (while 16.04 LTS has 3.16.3 so it is OK) without proprietary plugin. How did you installed printer on server?

Comment: Yes it's an HP M651dn on ethernet network. Reading up on CUPs website. I only print text files on occasion from the servers for documentation purposes usually.  Will need to delete existing jobs from the queue before additional attempts.

Comment: Solved (embarrassingly to say).  The printer showed as disabled with the command "lpstat -p".   So, I ran "lpadmin -p M651Admin -E -v ipp://192.168.129.245/ipp/print -m everywhere"  and now it is working.

Comment: You can answer you own question to help other user with possible similar problems :)